# ¿Cómo pasar una imagen desde JSP como array de bytes a un archivo en un Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Estoy programando una aplicación web desde NetBeans, utilizando Servlets y JSP, y utilizo operaciones que fueron programadas en java.

Mi problema es que al tomar una imagen desde el JSP, necesito que el servlet la reciba como un array de bytes. Para eso utilizo ServletInputStream, pero al momento de crear un archivo de tipo File me crea un archivo que el sistema operativo no conoce, como algo con sólo contenido binario.

El código en mi JSP es:

```
<form method="post" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="Aceptar"><br >
</form>
```

El código en mi Servlet es:

```
ServletInputStream is = request.getInputStream();
String s = is.toString();

File f = new File("/home/nicozeba/Escritorio/dataArch");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
byte[] buf =new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len=is.read(buf))>0){

   out.write(buf,0,len);
}

is.close();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo que tengo realizado con una web de libros solo cambia algunos parámetros.

En el HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="portada">Portada</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control" name="portada" id="portada">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

En el Servlet:

```
    Part filePart = request.getPart("portada");

    InputStream inputS = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;
    if(!getFileName(filePart).equals("")) {
        inputS = filePart.getInputStream();

        // Escalar la imagen
        BufferedImage imageBuffer = ImageIO.read(inputS);
        Image tmp = imageBuffer.getScaledInstance(640, 640, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
        BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(640, 640, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);

        os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(buffered, "jpg", os);
    }
```

os es el Array de Bytes.

Te añado tambien el metodo getFileName

```
private String getFileName(Part filePart) {
    for (String content : filePart.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if(content.trim().startsWith("filename"))
            return content.substring(content.indexOf("=")+1).trim().replace("\"", "");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con request.getInputStream lo que estas recuperando es todo el cuerpo de la petición:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()

Si lo que quieres es recuperar el contenido binario del parámetro "pic" debes leer el parametro de la peticion:

```
request.getParameter("pic");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: Cuidado. No se puede usar `ServletRequest#getParameter` para peticiones del tipo `multipart/form-data`. En estos casos, el formulario se ha enviado por partes. Aquí se tienen 2 cosas: si se trabaja con Servlet 2.x o anterior, usar la librería de Apache Commons FileUpload; si se trabaja con Servlet 3.x entonces ya lo soporta mediante la anotación `@MultipartConfig` y el método [`HttpServletRequest#getParts`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts--).